# why refresh div slow down and make my website die?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I implement javascript code which refresh my div every 10 seconds. It work well but I don't why it cause my website slow down and when I din''t used for few minutes it will make my website die. I don't know what happen on it because when I remove that javascript and my website do not faced that problem again. I don't know whether I am asking correct question or not but I hope I can get some help from you guys. Thanks in advanced.

This is my code :

```
<!------------------online-member--------------------------------->
<div id="refresh-member">
<div class="member-online-container">
    <p class="right-content-title">ALUMNUS are online</p>

    <div class="member-online-listing">
    <{section name=thisrsa loop=$online_member}>
        <ul>
            <li> 
                <img class="member-online-avatar" src="./images/hairstyles-for-men-with-short-hair-trend.jpg"/>
                <p class="member-online-name"> <{$online_member[thisrsa].name}></p>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <{/section}>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
<!------------------End- online-member--------------------------------->
 <script type="text/javascript">
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
$('#refresh-member').load('online-member.php');
}, 10000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds

</script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure about this but maybe try to clear the interval inside the function? 'window.clearInterval(auto_refresh);' before $('#refresh...

Comment: What browser and browser version does this happen with?

Comment: all browser I used also faced this problem. It will not immediately make my website slow down performance. It happening slowly when I start to run my website.